# fedora 27 kernel panic 4.16.7-200.fc27.x86_64

Tags: kernel, fedora, panic

For a fedora 27 vm running on a fedora 28 host, I did an "dnf update" and i'm now getting this kernel panic.  [image]How do I troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure how it happened, but changing the "CPU configuration" in the qemu/kvm definition to "Opteron_G5" got it back to working.